# How to make Canvas animation Background tranparent using three.js/dat.gui

Tags: javascript, css, canvas, three.js, dat.gui

I want to make this canvas as a background animation. But the three.js render the background to black. I want to make it transparent. I tried to change it by css `background-color:transparent;` I looked for other similar issues in stackoverflow but nothing helped. How can I do it? These are my html,css and js.
Thanks in advance.
Here is the [codepen link.](https://codepen.io/shimanto-rehman/pen/yLPygxX)
My HTML:

```
<canvas id="webgl-canvas"></canvas>
<!-- vertexShader -->
<script id="js-vertex-shader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
attribute vec3 position;
void main() {
  gl_Position = vec4(position, 1.0);
}
</script>

<!-- fragmentShader -->
<script id="js-fragment-shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
precision highp float;
uniform vec2 resolution;
uniform float time;
uniform float xScale;
uniform float yScale;
uniform float distortion;

void main() {
  vec2 p = (gl_FragCoord.xy * 2.0 - resolution) / min(resolution.x, resolution.y);
  
  float d = length(p) * distortion;
  
  float rx = p.x * (1.0 + d);
  float gx = p.x;
  float bx = p.x * (1.0 - d);

  float r = 0.05 / abs(p.y + sin((rx + time) * xScale) * yScale);
  float g = 0.05 / abs(p.y + sin((gx + time) * xScale) * yScale);
  float b = 0.05 / abs(p.y + sin((bx + time) * xScale) * yScale);
  
  gl_FragColor = vec4(r, g, b, 1.0);
}
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r124/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dat-gui/0.7.7/dat.gui.min.js"></script>
```

My CSS:

```
#webgl-canvas{
  width: 20% !important;
  height:10% !important;
  background: null !important;
}
```

My JS:

```
class Stage {
  constructor() {
    this.renderParam = {
      clearColor: 0xffffff,
      width: window.innerWidth,
      height: window.innerHeight
    };

    this.cameraParam = {
      left: -1,
      right: 1,
      top: 1,
      bottom: 1,
      near: 0,
      far: -1
    };

    this.scene = null;
    this.camera = null;
    this.renderer = null;
    this.geometry = null;
    this.material = null;
    this.mesh = null;

    this.isInitialized = false;
  }

  init() {
    this._setScene();
    this._setRender();
    this._setCamera();

    this.isInitialized = true;
  }

  _setScene() {
    this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
  }

  _setRender() {
    this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
      canvas: document.getElementById("webgl-canvas")
    });
    this.renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
    this.renderer.setClearColor(new THREE.Color(this.renderParam.clearColor));
    this.renderer.setSize(this.renderParam.width, this.renderParam.height);
  }

  _setCamera() {
    if (!this.isInitialized) {
      this.camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(
        this.cameraParam.left,
        this.cameraParam.right,
        this.cameraParam.top,
        this.cameraParam.bottom,
        this.cameraParam.near,
        this.cameraParam.far
      );
    }
    
    const windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
    const windowHeight = window.innerHeight;

    this.camera.aspect = windowWidth / windowHeight;

    this.camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    this.renderer.setSize(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  }

  _render() {
    this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
  }

  onResize() {
    this._setCamera();
  }

  onRaf() {
    this._render();
  }
}

class Mesh {
  constructor(stage) {
    this.canvas = document.getElementById("webgl-canvas");
    this.canvasWidth = this.canvas.width;
    this.canvasHeight = this.canvas.height;

    this.uniforms = {
      resolution: { type: "v2", value: [ this.canvasWidth, this.canvasHeight ] },
      time: { type: "f", value: 0.0 },
      xScale: { type: "f", value: 1.0 },
      yScale: { type: "f", value: 0.5 },
      distortion: { type: "f", value: 0.050 }
    };

    this.stage = stage;

    this.mesh = null;
    
    this.xScale = 1.0;
    this.yScale = 0.5;
    this.distortion = 0.050;
  }

  init() {
    this._setMesh();
    // this._setGui();
  }

  _setMesh() {
    const position = [
      -1.0, -1.0, 0.0,
       1.0, -1.0, 0.0,
      -1.0,  1.0, 0.0,
       1.0, -1.0, 0.0,
      -1.0,  1.0, 0.0,
       1.0,  1.0, 0.0
    ];

    const positions = new THREE.BufferAttribute(new Float32Array(position), 3);

    const geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
    geometry.setAttribute("position", positions);

    const material = new THREE.RawShaderMaterial({
      vertexShader: document.getElementById("js-vertex-shader").textContent,
      fragmentShader: document.getElementById("js-fragment-shader").textContent,
      uniforms: this.uniforms,
      side: THREE.DoubleSide
    });

    this.mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

    this.stage.scene.add(this.mesh);
  }
  
  _diffuse() {
    
  }
  
  _render() {
    this.uniforms.time.value += 0.01;
  }

  _setGui() {
    const parameter = {
      xScale: this.xScale,
      yScale: this.yScale,
      distortion: this.distortion
    }
    const gui = new dat.GUI();
    gui.add(parameter, "xScale", 0.00, 5.00, 0.01).onChange((value) => {
      this.mesh.material.uniforms.xScale.value = value;
    });
    gui.add(parameter, "yScale", 0.00, 1.00, 0.01).onChange((value) => {
      this.mesh.material.uniforms.yScale.value = value;
    });
    gui.add(parameter, "distortion", 0.001, 0.100, 0.001).onChange((value) => {
      this.mesh.material.uniforms.distortion.value = value;
    });
  }

  onRaf() {
    this._render();
  }
}

(() => {
  const stage = new Stage();

  stage.init();

  const mesh = new Mesh(stage);

  mesh.init();

  window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
    stage.onResize();
  });
  
  window.addEventListener("load", () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      mesh._diffuse();
    }, 1000);
  });

  const _raf = () => {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
      stage.onRaf();
      mesh.onRaf();

      _raf();
    });
  };

  _raf();
})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to get alpha support with three.js's `WebGLRenderer` at all you need to activate it's alpha buffer by setting the `alpha` option to true upon initialization.

```
this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    alpha: true,
    canvas: document.getElementById("webgl-canvas")
});
```

As your using a `RawShaderMaterial`, the source of you texture's pixel opacity **is** the fragment shader.

If we take a look at it

```
gl_FragColor = vec4(r, g, b, 1.0);
```

we realize that whatever color a pixel will have, it's always opaque. That means you need to do your alpha calculations inside the fragment shader. One possible way would be using a treshold e.g. if red+green+blue is smaller than 0.5 make it completely transparent.

```
float a = 1.0;
if (r + g + b < 0.5) {
    a = 0.0;
}
gl_FragColor = vec4(r, g, b, a);
```

Apart from that you also need to **get rid** of your custom clear color:

```
this.renderer.setClearColor(new THREE.Color(this.renderParam.clearColor));
```

and give your RawShaderMaterial the additional options `transparent: true, opacity: 1`

Here's an example:

```js
class Stage {
    constructor() {
        this.renderParam = {
            width: window.innerWidth,
            height: window.innerHeight
        };

        this.cameraParam = {
            left: -1,
            right: 1,
            top: 1,
            bottom: 1,
            near: 0,
            far: -1
        };

        this.scene = null;
        this.camera = null;
        this.renderer = null;
        this.geometry = null;
        this.material = null;
        this.mesh = null;

        this.isInitialized = false;
    }

    init() {
        this._setScene();
        this._setRender();
        this._setCamera();

        this.isInitialized = true;
    }

    _setScene() {
        this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
    }

    _setRender() {
        this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
            alpha: true,
            canvas: document.getElementById("webgl-canvas")
        });
        this.renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);

        this.renderer.setSize(this.renderParam.width, this.renderParam.height);
    }

    _setCamera() {
        if (!this.isInitialized) {
            this.camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(
                this.cameraParam.left,
                this.cameraParam.right,
                this.cameraParam.top,
                this.cameraParam.bottom,
                this.cameraParam.near,
                this.cameraParam.far
            );
        }

        const windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
        const windowHeight = window.innerHeight;

        this.camera.aspect = windowWidth / windowHeight;

        this.camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
        this.renderer.setSize(windowWidth, windowHeight);
    }

    _render() {
        this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
    }

    onResize() {
        this._setCamera();
    }

    onRaf() {
        this._render();
    }
}

class Mesh {
    constructor(stage) {
        this.canvas = document.getElementById("webgl-canvas");
        this.canvasWidth = this.canvas.width;
        this.canvasHeight = this.canvas.height;

        this.uniforms = {
            resolution: {
                type: "v2",
                value: [this.canvasWidth, this.canvasHeight]
            },
            time: {
                type: "f",
                value: 0.0
            },
            xScale: {
                type: "f",
                value: 1.0
            },
            yScale: {
                type: "f",
                value: 0.5
            },
            distortion: {
                type: "f",
                value: 0.050
            }
        };

        this.stage = stage;

        this.mesh = null;

        this.xScale = 1.0;
        this.yScale = 0.5;
        this.distortion = 0.050;
    }

    init() {
        this._setMesh();
        // this._setGui();
    }

    _setMesh() {
        const position = [
            -1.0, -1.0, 0.0,
            1.0, -1.0, 0.0,
            -1.0, 1.0, 0.0,
            1.0, -1.0, 0.0,
            -1.0, 1.0, 0.0,
            1.0, 1.0, 0.0
        ];

        const positions = new THREE.BufferAttribute(new Float32Array(position), 3);

        const geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
        geometry.setAttribute("position", positions);

        const material = new THREE.RawShaderMaterial({
            vertexShader: document.getElementById("js-vertex-shader").textContent,
            fragmentShader: document.getElementById("js-fragment-shader").textContent,
            uniforms: this.uniforms,
      transparent: true,
      opacity: 1,
            side: THREE.DoubleSide
        });

        this.mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

        this.stage.scene.add(this.mesh);
    }

    _diffuse() {
        // gsap.to(this.mesh.material.uniforms.xScale, {
        //   value: 2,
        //   duration: 0.1,
        //   ease: 'power2.inOut',
        //   repeat: -1,
        //   yoyo: true
        // });
        // gsap.to(this.mesh.material.uniforms.yScale, {
        //   value: 1,
        //   duration: 0.1,
        //   ease: 'power2.inOut',
        //   repeat: -1,
        //   yoyo: true
        // });
    }

    _render() {
        this.uniforms.time.value += 0.01;
    }

    _setGui() {
        const parameter = {
            xScale: this.xScale,
            yScale: this.yScale,
            distortion: this.distortion
        }
        const gui = new dat.GUI();
        gui.add(parameter, "xScale", 0.00, 5.00, 0.01).onChange((value) => {
            this.mesh.material.uniforms.xScale.value = value;
        });
        gui.add(parameter, "yScale", 0.00, 1.00, 0.01).onChange((value) => {
            this.mesh.material.uniforms.yScale.value = value;
        });
        gui.add(parameter, "distortion", 0.001, 0.100, 0.001).onChange((value) => {
            this.mesh.material.uniforms.distortion.value = value;
        });
    }

    onRaf() {
        this._render();
    }
}

(() => {
    const stage = new Stage();

    stage.init();

    const mesh = new Mesh(stage);

    mesh.init();

    window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
        stage.onResize();
    });

    window.addEventListener("load", () => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            mesh._diffuse();
        }, 1000);
    });

    const _raf = () => {
        window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
            stage.onRaf();
            mesh.onRaf();

            _raf();
        });
    };

    _raf();
})();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r124/three.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dat-gui/0.7.7/dat.gui.min.js"></script>
     <canvas id="webgl-canvas"></canvas>
<!-- vertexShader -->
<script id="js-vertex-shader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
attribute vec3 position;
void main() {
  gl_Position = vec4(position, 1.0);
}
</script>

<!-- fragmentShader -->
<script id="js-fragment-shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
precision highp float;
uniform vec2 resolution;
uniform float time;
uniform float xScale;
uniform float yScale;
uniform float distortion;

void main() {
  vec2 p = (gl_FragCoord.xy * 2.0 - resolution) / min(resolution.x, resolution.y);
  
  float d = length(p) * distortion;
  
  float rx = p.x * (1.0 + d);
  float gx = p.x;
  float bx = p.x * (1.0 - d);

  float r = 0.05 / abs(p.y + sin((rx + time) * xScale) * yScale);
  float g = 0.05 / abs(p.y + sin((gx + time) * xScale) * yScale);
  float b = 0.05 / abs(p.y + sin((bx + time) * xScale) * yScale);
  
  float a = 1.0;
  if(r+g+b<0.5)
  {
  a=0.0;
  }

  gl_FragColor = vec4(r, g, b, a);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much @obscure. it works. many many thanks <3

Comment: Glad I could help @SMShimantoRehman - By the way, If you think this is the correct answer please consider accepting it using the tick.

Comment: I did it. Sorry, I don't know the the Stackoverflow culture properly yet. Again, thanks for letting me know <3 @obscure